# Render selected triangles in different colour?

Tags: opengl, directx, rendering, shader, mesh

I was wondering what the best approach would be to render selected triangles on a mesh in a different colour? I'm using OpenGL but the specific rendering system probably doesn't  matter so much.

One approach would be to render the selected triangles over the top of the existing mesh, but I feel there must be a better way to do this using shaders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this is to create a separate colour buffer for your triangles. You can subsequently use `glBufferSubData()` (see [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBufferSubData.xml)) to revert the colour of deselected triangles, and update the colour on those that are newly selected that frame.

This assumes you know which index in your buffer the vertices of the triangles whose colour you want to change are located at.

It is also possible to let the additional buffer contain boolean values only, and overwrite the colour of selected triangle(s) with a value specified in a uniform variable.

Comment: Would this not cause interpolation on primitives during rasterization which had either 1 or 2 of it's vertices set to the selected colour? How would such a colour buffer be represented/created?

Comment: Only if your vertices are reused in your original model's buffers. If they are all defined as separate vertices there is no problem. This is a limitation of OpenGL unfortunately. Since you're trying to visualise selected triangles, you're going to have to keep track of a lot of different boolean values whether a particular triangle should be marked or not. It's not feasible to have this in a single uniform buffer, so separating the triangles and using a single buffer is the best solution here as far as I can tell.

Comment: The idea is that you first take your original vertex buffer(s) and index buffer, and look up all vertices in the vertex buffer using the index buffer, storing all vertices as a single sequence in a new buffer. Since all triangle vertices are now "separate" vertices, you can specify individual colours for each of them. You only really need a single byte per vertex here. Create another vertex buffer, possibly initialise all values to 0, and add it as another attribute to your shader. Subsequently you check whether the input is set to 1 and if so override the colour of the vertex.

Comment: Ok so creating another VBO from the "flattened out" vertex buffer basically, adding it as an input to the vertex shader and passing it through to the fragment shader should do the trick you say? Will try this out anyway sounds promising.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying :)